# Why some of the Clojure functions in clojure.core are not documented?

Tags: clojure

I found some of the Clojure functions in clojure.core are not documented.

Some of them are private functions. But others like `chunk-*` and `await1` and so on are public but do not have documents. Does that have a specially meaning, or just because of they are new added functions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The undocumented functions in clojure.core are considered to be part of the implementation, not part of the public interface (so the lack of docstring is intentional). In some cases, undoc'ed functions are called by the expansion of public macros so they must be public.